# jquery cycle through fade divs

Tags: jquery, cycle

i need to make all the DIV's display none while the first shows on page load. at the moment they all show at once then gradually disappear and the rotator works as it should once its cylced through the first time.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.testimonialrotator = function(o) {

    var defaults = {
        settings_slideshowTime : '5',
        settings_autoHeight : 'on'
    }

    o = $.extend(defaults, o);
    this.each( function() {
        var cthis = jQuery(this);
        var cchildren = cthis.children();
        var currNr=0;
        var timebuf=0;
        var slideshowTime = parseInt(o.settings_slideshowTime);
        setInterval(tick, 1000);
        cthis.height(cchildren.eq(currNr).height());
        cchildren.eq(0).css('position', 'absolute');
        function tick(){
            timebuf++;
            if(timebuf>slideshowTime){
                timebuf=0;
                gotoNext();
            }
        }
        function gotoNext(){
            var arg=currNr+1;
            if(arg>cchildren.length-1){
            arg=0;
            }
            cchildren.eq(currNr).fadeOut('slow');
            cchildren.eq(arg).fadeIn('slow');
            if(o.settings_autoHeight=='on'){
                cthis.animate({'height' : cchildren.eq(arg).height()})
            }
            currNr=arg;
        }
        return this;
    })
}
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: provide demo with enough css to replicate in jsfiddle.net. Likely some css fixes could be added

Answer (score 1):

Quickest solution would be to just apply display none as an inline style.

Alternatively in a script tag just apply display none to the elements you want hidden: on load, not in the jquery ready.

Answer (score 1):

I would ad something like this...

```
$('my_divs').hide();
$('my_divs').first().show();
```

into your script before you do anything else.